# Different layouts depending on checkbox

Tags: java, android, eclipse

There are `4 checkboxes` and a `button` and as default all checkboxes are `checked`. Upon button click I need to test to see if any checkboxes are deselcted and if one is then the next activity (that the button launches) needs to hide a text input box. Right now I have it checking like:

```
if (!picCheck.isChecked()) {
    intent.putExtra(PIC_CHECK, 1);
} else {
    intent.putExtra(PIC_CHECK, 2);
}
```

This basically will send the next activity a message with a value of either 1 or 2,

1. being **deselcted**

   2 being **selected**.

Then in the next activity I would hide textbox if that message == 1.

On an unrelated note does this look correct?

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventNameBox);
    String nameMessage = editText.getText().toString();
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventLocationBox);
    String locMessage = editText.getText().toString();
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.aboutEvent);
```

Will this convert whatever is in the eventNameBox, eventLocationBox and aboutEvent into strings? The next code after that is:

```
    intent.putExtra(NAME_MESSAGE, nameMessage);
    intent.putExtra(LOCATION_MESSAGE, locMessage);
    intent.putExtra(ABOUT_MESSAGE, aboutMessage);
```

This will work?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to hide the `TextView` why don't you just use

```
 textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

this will hide the `TextView`

Comment: Kind of... I want to hide a text box on a new activity, not the same activity as the check boxes. If that makes sense? Basically the 4 check boxes are 16 different outcomes for the layout. EX: hiding a but not b c or d. hiding a and b but not c or d.

Comment: you set the textview's visibility on the second activity's onCreate() after checking the received extras

Comment: you set the visibility of your textviews(a, b, c or d) just as you want on the second activity(GONE to hide/VISIBLE to show)

Comment: Right, I figured that much. Is it possible if let's say the middle text box is hidden then it pushes the others up so it doesn't look sloppy? My code crashes when I hit the create button. Is that code up top valid? Edit: are you saying in the first activity I can set what the next activity hides/doesnt?

Comment: using GONE will remove entirely the view from the activity, which means that the other views will go up..as for the second question using the same edittext to define all views isn't good.. try defining an edittext for each view

Comment: I hope I understood you right. No you don't do that in the first Activity.. here's the scenario: you send extras from the first activity and receive it in the send, that's when you make your test and do the hide/display..did I make myself clear?